# Teradata - Find the Teradata servers I can connect from linux

Tags: teradata, database-connectivity

We have a Linux UAT machine on which our datastage, shell, teradata scripts are configured and we can execute jobs/scripts from this server.  We have different Teradata environments(SIT, UAT, PAT, PROD -  all are different servers).  I can connect to SIT, UAT Teradata using the

```
bteq .logon
```

command from the linux server;  But not able to connect to Teradata PAT or PROD.

How can I know the list of TD servers (SIT, UAT, PAT, PROD) that I can connect from this Linux server.  (Is there any file on this Linux server where the list of all TD servers that it can connect to is stored).  I had verified the /etc/hosts file, it has contents relative to other unix/linux servers to which we do NDM and other stuff; but no info. related to Teradata. I am looking to get this info. from the Linux server itself as I have access to this one only.

Answer (score 0):

Which Teradata servers are available depends on your network configuration.
As far as I know, there is no configuration file listing available Teradata servers.

The `.logon`s first argument is the `TDPID`. That may be a single IP-adress or a hostname mentioned in /etc/hosts.
Usually if the IP-adress or host is reachable in your network, you are able to connect via bteq or any other client.

A Teradata server consists of nodes,  each a completly independent working UNIX machine, with its own IP-address.
Therefore you may find a list of IP-Addresses with hostnames ending in `cop<n>` , e.g. tddevcop1, tddevcop2 in your /etc/hosts. 
If you do a `.login tddev/user,password` (some magic going on) one of the nodes is choosen as your contact (and that node has to do the parsing and communication work, distributing the real workload to all the nodes).

My best bet: Ask the DBA (or Network Admin) about your specific network.